# RPM Installed With Different Name

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

Basically one rpm has a dependency on another rpm. But when I try to install the other rpm, it changed "-" (dash) to "_" (underscore) in the name. See text circled in red from the screenshot.

Now because the system automatically changed the name. My first rpm is not able to find that installed rpm. What's going on? How to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## solution to your problem

The package you are installing is too old. You need at least version 0.12, you are installing 0.10.1.

## concerning the naming

It would seem that the filename does not correspond to the package name. You can query the "properties" of the file like this:

```
rpm -qip ./rpms/python-importlib-metadata-0.10.1.noarch.rpm
```

I suspect that the output will say:

```
Name: python-importlib_metadata
```

meaning that the real package name has an underscore, and that the filename does not correspond. It is possible that the package provides both names (it probably was renamed at some point). You can check this using:

```
rpm -qp ./rpms/python-importlib-metadata-0.10.1.noarch.rpm --provides
```

I expect the output to say something like:

```
python-importlib-metadata = 0.10.1
python-importlib_metadata = 0.10.1
```

(both with dash and underscore), meaning that it will work for dependencies with both namings.

Comment: Got you. The version I'm installing is actually 0.18-1 by the way. So it's not too old. The output of the name does say `python-importlib_metadata = 0.18-1` though. So you're right on that part. But my other rpm is looking for the wrongly named rpm. How to resolve from there?

Comment: then I think you should look for another rpm, online I find: https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-importlib-metadata multiple packages with dashes in the name, they also say that they provide `python-importlib-metadata`, for example: https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/updates/testing/31/armhfp/Packages/p/python3-importlib-metadata-0.23-1.fc31.noarch.html, so I would recommend looking for another rpm package for python-importlib-metadata